# WebApp, open mobile camera with one click? VueJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, camera

Currently building a web app I also want to make mobile-friendly as well. Currently it uses. I want to know if there is a way to open a mobile camera with one click? I am currently using <input with type="file" but this asks to 'choose file' (or can be amended to open camera) [image]

but I want it to skip this step and directly open a native camera. Example code;

```
      <q-dialog v-if="mobileMode" v-model="webcamBol.webCamIDBackBol">
        <q-card
          ><q-card-section
            ><q-btn
              style="float: right"
              q-btn
              icon="close"
              flat
              @click="closeWebCamBol"
            ></q-btn>
            <input
              class="q-mt-md"
              type="file"
              id="fileLoader"
              capture="user"
              @change="previewIdBack"
              size="xs"
            />
            <div>
              <br />
              <q-btn
                :disabled="imgBtnDisabled"
                :color="
                  accounttype == 'centralized' ? 'light-blue-7' : 'primary'
                "
                :label="$t('settings.useImg')"
                @click="useIDBackImage"
                size="xs"
                style="margin-left: 5px"
              ></q-btn>
            </div> </q-card-section></q-card
      ></q-dialog>
      <q-dialog
        v-else
        v-model="webcamBol.webCamIDBackBol"
        @show="openWebCam"
        @before-hide="closeWebCam"
        persistent
      >
        <q-card style="height: 70vh">
          <q-btn
            style="float: right"
            q-btn
            icon="close"
            flat
            @click="closeWebCamBol"
          ></q-btn>
          <web-cam
            ref="webcam"
            :device-id="deviceId"
            width="100%"
            @started="onStarted"
            @stopped="onStopped"
            @error="onError"
            @cameras="onCameras"
            @notsupported="unsupportedBrowser"
            @camera-change="onCameraChange"
          />
          <div
            v-if="cameraError == false"
            class="row"
            style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 10px"
          >
            <h6>{{ $t("settings.holdIdBack") }}</h6>
            <q-btn
              style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 40px"
              color="primary"
              :label="$t('settings.capture')"
              @click="onIDBackCapture"
            ></q-btn>
          </div>
        </q-card>
      </q-dialog>
      <q-dialog v-model="webcamBol.idBackPhotoBol" persistent>
        <q-card>
          <figure class="figure">
            <img :src="photoType.idBack" style="padding-top: 20px" />
          </figure>
          <q-card-section>
            <div class="row">
              <q-btn
                color="primary"
                :label="$t('settings.useImg')"
                @click="useIDBackImage"
                style="margin-right: 10px"
              ></q-btn>
              <q-btn
                color="primary"
                :label="$t('settings.retake')"
                @click="retakeIDBack"
              ></q-btn>
            </div>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </q-dialog>
```